# Communicate with a specific client [JS/PY]

Tags: python, django, angular, server, client

I use angular client side (TS) and Django server side (PY).

Unfortunately despite what I find on the internet, I can't send a message to a SPECIFIC client from the server. Socket.io doesn't exist in PY, I've seen the websockets but that only talks about sending a message to ALL clients in a group. But if I want to send a message only to a client B I don't see how to do it.

Please help me, and guide me on the solution to use

PS: I'm starting with the PY backend, be indulgent.

Thank you.

Comment: The general idea is (I don’t know Django specifically) to store the client id in an array on the server on a connect event. Then use that array to find the specific client and only sent a message to that client.

Comment: Yes it works the same with socket.io and it makes sense. I have already implemented this, but however, the problem is there, what should be used to be able to send from the server to the client?